# Type Error opening python file for reading

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running into an issue trying to open a text file for reading in Python 3. The code is as follows:

```
def main():
the_file = input('What is the name of the file?')

open_file = open(the_file,"r","utf8")
open_file.read()
```

and then I'm calling the function.

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Matthew/Desktop/CaesarCipher.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Matthew/Desktop/CaesarCipher.py", line 7, in main
    open_file = open(encrypted_file,"r","utf8")
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It's unclear to me where I am using an incorrect type... can I get some insight as to why this isn't working?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd argument to `open()` is `buffering`:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
     errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None) -> file object
```

Pass the character encoding as a keyword parameter instead:

```
with open(the_file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = file.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue:

```
open_file = open(the_file,"r")
```

The **third** parameter is a [buffer parameter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), not a encoding?

So what you could do is:

```
open_file = open(the_file,"r", 1, 'utf-8') # 1 == line Buffered reading
```

Also..
You should do this instead:

```
with open(the_file, 'rb') as fh:
    data = fh.read().decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
with open(the_file, 'r', -1, 'utf-8') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
```

Cleaner, you get "control" over the decoding and won't end up with open filehandles or wrongful encodings.

Comment: `open()` function in Python 2 and Python 3 have different parameters e.g., `open()` funciton in Python 2 doesn't have `encoding` parameter. Don't link to Python 2 docs for Python 3 question.

Comment: `buffering=1` means *line* buffering (it doesn't merely mean that the buffering is enabled e.g., the default `buffering=-1` means that the buffer size is equal to `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`).

Comment: File opened in a text mode `'r'` yields Unicode strings. It is incorrect to call `.decode('utf-8')` on them (`str` object has no attribute 'decode' in Python 3)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thank you for the corrections, the link was just a type-o on my behalf.. I knew the third parameter was the same across version and when goggling it i just took the first link.. Should have paid more attention to the version and i'm sorry :)
Also yes, `.decode()` died with Python2 so made some slight modifications to my answer!